# Как выполнить код в .cs файле через консоль, не создавая при этом project и не используя IDE?

Tags: c#, .net, консоль

Я только начал изучать C#. Делаю лабораторные работы по синтаксису языка, по книге C# 10 Quick Syntax Reference, автор M.Olsson. Одна глава — одна лаба. Лабораторная работа должна быть в виде файла cs. Что бы проверяющий мог его запустить из консоли. Дело в том, что я не совсем понимаю как мне это делать не создавая проект с program.cs под каждую лабу.  Нагуглил, что dotnet run может запускать только целый проект а не отдельный cs файл. А мне нужно условно, в одной папке 30 (количество глав в учебнике) cs файлов по главам, или 30 папок и в каждой по cs файлу. И что бы любой файл можно было запустить из консоли и код в нем выполнился. Как в питоне, когда можно запустить любой py файл.

Comment: Скорее всего никак. Точка входа в любое приложение на C# - метод `Main`. Файлы с расширением `cs` - всего лишь код, который сначала надо скомпилировать в исполняемый файл, а затем запустить. Или вы можете скомпилить в `dll` и попробовать запустить через `dotnet run`, однако вероятно в любом случае нужен будет метод `Main`

Comment: В Windows компилятор командной строки `csc` и запуск скомпилированного .exe устроит?..

Comment: Имеется ввиду скорее всего отправка program.cs файла под каждую лабу.
А как проверяющий его будет запускать - это уже не ваша проблема

Comment: Насколько я помню, Троелсен в своих книгах расписывал, как компилировать код из консоли, с подключением всех необходимых библиотек и пр. Но было это во времена стародавние, для .NET Framework.

Comment: Спасибо за варианты. @Harry  да, такой вариант должен устроить. Но есть такой интересный нюанс. В рандомном cs фале, который находится в папке без какого либо проекта, следующий код: int binNumber = 0b0100; не обрабатывается и я в консоли получаю сообщение об ошибке cs1002, просит после "0" перед "b" поставить точку с запятой. Видимо отладчик csc.exe не понимает бинарные литералы. А когда тот же код я запускаю в проекте, в файле program.cs - все работает. dotnet run и csc.exe работают по разному?

Comment: Это **весь** текст в файле? Например, вот такой файл, как в https://ideone.com/ATi7xp, вполне нормально компилируется и работает. Что конкретно вам говорит компилятор?

Comment: @Harry, весь текст представлен здесь: https://ideone.com/eHU34x, странно что в этом онлайн редакторе все работает, а в vs code нет. В командной строке мне выдает: "ch3.cs(40,26): error CS1002: ожидалась ;". Это после команды командной строке: C:\Users\varta\Desktop\Labs\3_variables> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe ch3.cs

Comment: Тут не подскажу, в чем проблема, C# не настолько мне близок...